# Using dictionaries to multiply columns like by reference Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reference, name-binding

I have a data frame like this and I would like to multiply the rows by its references value in another data frame using pandas. After that I would like to add all products from those rows and store it in a column called Pro_Sum. I know Python doesn't pass things by reference, but I can name-bind in here so I'm trying to create a dictionary to multiply the values according to its name, but I haven't been successful.

```
df = pd.read_excel (C:/"dummy")
d = {"C1": 2, "C2": 5,"C3":4, "C4":1}
df.mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1)

prod = d.keys() 
df[prod] = df[prod].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1)[prod]
to_sum_t = list(df)
#.sum ignores the none numeric values.
df['Pro_sum'] = df[to_sum_t].sum(axis=1)
```

Input

```
ID  AU  HP  Name1   Value1  CHC1    Name2 Value2 CHC2   Name3 Value3 CHC3 
1   4   3   C1        10    100      0      0       0     0      0      0       
2   6   2   C2        20    95      C1      6       5     0      0      0    
3   2   7   C3        4     40      C4      6       60    0      0      0   
4   8   9   C1        8     100      0      0       0     0      0      0    
5   2   6   C1        6     10      C2      15      86   C4      1      4
```

Reference column

```
Names Values
  C1    2
  C2    5
  C3    4
  C4    1
  Example row 5 Pro_Sum = 6*2 + 15*5 + 1*1 = 88
```

Minimal Output

```
ID  AU  HP  Name1 Value1 CHC1   Name2 Value2 CHC2   Name3 Value3 CHC3 Pro_Sum
1   4   3   C1      10    100      0    0     0       0      0      0    20 
2   6   2   C2      20    95      C1    6     5       0      0      0    112
5   2   6   C1       6    10      C2    15    86      C4     1      4    88
```

Comment: Not sure if understand, `df[prod]` cannot select columns names in sample data, because not exist same as keys as dict.

Comment: so should I rename all my columns' header to the name that I want refer in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) columns by names, [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) values by dictionary and convert to numpy arrays by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), multiple, sum and assign to new column:

```
d = {"C1": 2, "C2": 5,"C3":4, "C4":1}

a = df.filter(like='Name').replace(d).astype(int).values
b = df.filter(like='Value').values

df['Pro_Sum'] = (a * b).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  AU  HP Name1  Value1  CHC1 Name2  Value2  CHC2 Name3  Value3  CHC3  \
0   1   4   3    C1      10   100     0       0     0     0       0     0   
1   2   6   2    C2      20    95    C1       6     5     0       0     0   
2   3   2   7    C3       4    40    C4       6    60     0       0     0   
3   4   8   9    C1       8   100     0       0     0     0       0     0   
4   5   2   6    C1       6    10    C2      15    86    C4       1     4   

   Pro_Sum  
0       20  
1      112  
2       22  
3       16  
4       88
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying to use the code and I'm getting this error that says `invalid literal for long() with base 10: '    C1'` I don't why it doesn't recognize C1 as a string.

Comment: @Zesima29 - There is whitespace before `' C1'`, if use previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025752/2901002) need `df['Zone'] = df['Zone'].str.strip().map(d)` and then in this solution is possible remove `replace(d)`

Comment: @Zesima29 - If column name is different, change `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.strip().map(d)`

Comment: Okay where should I add this line of code? `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.strip().map(d)` I was working on exceptions handlers that were supposed to NaN the final product if the column name wasn't in the dictionary. But that line of your will clean all the columns of bad characters.

Comment: You can add this code before previosu answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025986/2901002) - there is zone column which values need be replaced by dictionary in answer above. Only here is no columns called zone but Name