# pivot to compute new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'mth':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'dy':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'id':[1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frame':['Fo','Fm','Fp','Fmp','Fp','Fmp','Fp','Fmp'],'param':['p1','p1','p1','p1','p2','p2','p3','p3'], 'avg':[0.1,0.25,0.1,0.25,0.08,0.26,0.05,0.25]}).set_index(['mth','dy'])
testdf2 = pd.DataFrame({'mth':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'dy':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'id':[1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'frame':['Fo','Fm','Fp','Fmp','Fp','Fmp','Fp','Fmp'], 'param':['p1','p1','p1','p1','p2','p2','p3','p3'],'avg':[0.1,0.25,0.1,0.25,0.08,0.26,0.05,0.25]}).set_index(['mth','dy'])
mydf = pd.concat([testdf,testdf2])
```

I have some data in long format and need to compute new values for each `param` based on pairs of `frame`.  In the apply(print) statement below you can see the relationship betwee frame and param. unfortunately for my first `param` I have duplicated data - perhaps it would be easiest to remove rows corresponding to id 5 and 6.

```
mydf.groupby(['mth','dy','param']).apply(print)

        id frame param   avg
mth dy                      
1   1    1    Fo    p1  0.10
    1    2    Fm    p1  0.25
    1    5    Fp    p1  0.10
    1    6   Fmp    p1  0.25
        id frame param   avg
mth dy                      
1   1    7    Fp    p2  0.08
    1    8   Fmp    p2  0.26
        id frame param   avg
mth dy                      
1   1    9    Fp    p3  0.05
    1   10   Fmp    p3  0.25
```

one approach i've considered is

```
mydf = mydf.query('(param!="p1") | (param=="p1" & (frame=="Fo" | frame=="Fm"))')

mydf.groupby(['mth','dy','param']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1].avg - x.iloc[0].avg)
```

but if your data gets out of order somehow you'd get the wrong answer. I'd like to use `pivot` or a related function so I can use something to the effect of Fm - Fo or Fmp - Fp and access the values by name.
However,  I can't seem to find a solution that appends a new column `param_val` to the existing dataframe where the `param_val` is duplicated for each `frame`.

at the very least, I think I'd need to sort it by `p1` and not `p1`, eg. `mydf.query('param=="p1"')` and `mydf.query('param!="p1"')` before pivoting but then there should be a fairly concise columnar operation that eludes me.

I did look at [Pivot duplicates rows into new columns Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025752/pivot-duplicates-rows-into-new-columns-pandas) but haven't wrapped my head around it. pivoting in pandas is super complicated compared to R!
your help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: your issue is that the avg value is duplicated? Why not include it in your grouping - `mydf.groupby(['mth','dy','param','avg']).first()`

Comment: if you group `avg` then you can't pivot and compute a new column with it....

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you set `as_index=False` on your `groupby` operation you can still apply any functions to the avg column. Could you be a little clearer about what you expect the output to look like?